# Log in with twitter4j callback

Tags: android, callback, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I try to write an application where an user can log in on twitter. I use twitter4j like library.My problem is that when I go in the page where I must put username and password, the program block because i don't know use callback to came in my application. Someone can me help?

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private Twitter twitter;
RequestToken requestToken;
final public static String CALLBACK_SCHEME = "x-latify-oauth-twitter";
final public static String CALLBACK_URL = CALLBACK_SCHEME + "://callback";
private Uri uri;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new updateTwitterStatus().execute();

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    twitter.shutdown();
}

class updateTwitterStatus extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String testStatus = "prova tweet ";

        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();

        // the following is set without accesstoken- desktop client
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
                .setOAuthConsumerKey("******")
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret(
                        "*****");

        try {
            TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
            twitter = tf.getInstance();
            Log.i("bauu", "miao");

            requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
            String authUrl = requestToken.getAuthenticationURL();
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
            uri = Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL());

            return authUrl;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(s)));    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your callback URL in twitter dev app options are as follows,

```
http://YOUR-URL/app://YOUR-APP-HOST
```

and within your android manifest file, in between the   of the actvitiy that takes you to twitter, 
make sure you define:

```
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
              android:host="YOUR-APP-HOST"
              android:scheme="app" />
          </intent-filter>
```

lastly, make sure in your program,

```
final public static String CALLBACK_URL = "app://YOUR-APP-HOST";
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer but i don't understand what I must write in dev app option in the callbackURL? and after the String CALLBACK_URL must be use in this way                                        requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(CALLBACK_URL);

Comment: on your dev.twitter.com account, where you registered your application. Make sure the url is in format as what i posted above

Comment: ah ok...but can i put any value?

Comment: yeah the host can be anyhting, aslong as you keep it the same everywhere

Comment: @rennoDeniro sorry but can you provide us an example? it should be like this:
http://www.dummy.com/sherlocknavigationdrawer://android
Or like this:
sherlocknavigationdrawer://android

In any case twitter throws me "Not a valid URL format", thanks!

Comment: Now it is working but when I try to repeat the process the:

requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(callbackScheme);

throws:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Access token already available

Comment: Well, it says it in the error what the issue is. When you're trying to repeat the process, the access token is already available therefore there's no need to go through the request process. Make a new question and link me to it so I can help.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter login in 4 easy steps:

1- Add *intent-filter* for your activity (Based on @rennoDeniro response) `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data
              android:host="twitter"
              android:scheme="myapp" />
 </intent-filter>
```

2- Define twitter key and secret in `strings.xml`

```
<string name="twitter_consumerKey">XXX</string>
<string name="twitter_consumerSecret">XXX</string>
```

3- Request twitter for signup page in `MainActivity.java`

```
public String CALLBACK_URL="myapp://twitter";
public Twitter twitter;
private static RequestToken rToken;


public void onLoginTwitter(View v) {
    (new RequestTwitterLoginTask()).execute();
}

class RequestTwitterLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        try
        {
            twitter.setOAuthConsumer(R.string.twitter_consumerKey, R.string.twitter_consumerSecret);
            String callbackURL = CALLBACK_URL;
            rToken= twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(callbackURL);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception: " + e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }            

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(rToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
    }
}
```

4- Handle Callback in `MainActivity.java`

```
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    if (this.getIntent()!=null && this.getIntent().getData()!=null){
        Uri uri = this.getIntent().getData();

        //handle returning from authenticating the user
        if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(CALLBACK_URL)) {
            String token = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_token");
            String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");

            try {
                Twitter t = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
                t.setOAuthConsumer(getResources().getString(R.string.twitter_consumerKey), getResources().getString(R.string.twitter_consumerSecret));

                AccessToken accessToken = t.getOAuthAccessToken(rToken,verifier);

                long userID = accessToken.getUserId();
                User user = t.showUser(userID);

                /* Do whatever you want */
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Twitter Exception: " + e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return;
        }
    }    

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Resume",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: 4 steps from what? the ops code? looks like I'll have to start from scratch and copy everything in, again.

Comment: 4 steps from source code generated by eclipse, or whatever you app written.

Comment: "4 steps from what?" lol, wherever you were when you got here. @VaishaliSutariya It's super late, but it sounds like your issue is completely unrelated to the login process. You need to create oath credentials at the (now) apps.twitter.com site before attempting to add login. They are used as the consumer key and secret above. They are NOT your username and password.