# Tweet from Android app - Couldn't find an app to open this

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I'm trying to implement a "Tweet from app" situation in my Android app.

**I do not want** to create an `Intent`, and start the activity with the browser, etc.

**I want to** authorize my app at the first run with the user's Twitter account, and after that send the tweets automatically.

Somebody mentioned [this tutorial](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/13/guide-to-integrating-twitter-android-application/) in an other question, and I started to implement this solution, but I got some errors (*"Couldn't find any app to open this"*): [image: My Android app with the _Couldn't find any app to open this_ error]

I've tried the *add the protocol to the callback url in Twitter dev* things (found on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991149/log-in-with-twitter4j-callback)), but the Twitter says:

> **Error**
>
> *Validation failed: Not a valid URL format*

Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry but maybe you can try [this](https://github.com/gorbin/ASNE)? just use asne-twitter?

Comment: Okay, I'm trying. Is there a detailed tutorial for it? Or just the one on the GitHub?

Comment: [Codeproject tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/815900/Android-social-network-integration)